# ! I can't find file `tikzlibraryshape.code.tex'

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, filesystem-access

I am using LaTeX and do not know how to fix this error

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryshape.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.5 \usetikzlibrary{shape, geometric,arrows}
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.5 \usetikzlibrary{shape, geometric,arrows}
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
9750 strings out of 493921
185027 string characters out of 3147261
224316 words of memory out of 3000000
12881 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
56i,0n,55p,445b,83s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: I don't know any library with the name `shape`. I just now `shapes.<something>` where "<something>" could be `geometric` or `symbols`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fourth line in your error block, you have

```
\usetikzlibrary{shape, geometric,arrows}
```

Neither `shape` nor `geometric` are names of libraries. There is a collection of libraries called `shapes`, and one of the libraries in that collection is `shapes.geometric`. Hence, you probably want either

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
```

or

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my installation (TeXLive 2016 on Ubuntu) the file is actually named `texlibraryshapes.code.tex` (note the s) and is located in tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries. So, if some package is caling for the file as `texlibraryshape` without the s, that seems like an error. Are you sure that you have the `pgf` package installed?

Comment: Regarding that last comment, if `pgf` was not installed, then that error would never occur, because `\usetikzlibrary` would be undefined, and thus it would never have known to look for a file called `tikzlibrary<libraryname>.code.tex` in the first place. And before that, an error would have occurred at `\usepackage{tikz}`.